# Control page setup options in Delphi without showing Page Setup dialog

Tags: delphi, printing, twebbrowser, page-setup

In my Delphi application, I can use the following code to show the Page Setup dialog to my users before printing.

```
//WebHTML is a TWebBrowser with a Document loaded.
WebHTML.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER);
```

[image: Page Setup Dialog]

Is it possible to change these page setup options using code (without showing the Page Setup dialog to my users)?  I specifically want to control the Header and Footer options so that all users will have the same headers and footers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page setup settings are saved and loaded using Windows Registry keys.  I wrote code to change the keys at the location "Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup".

[image: Internet Explorer Page Setup registry keys]